# Linux permissions for WinSCP'ing into Apache site

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions, winscp

I'm running an Ubuntu server with apache2/mod_mono

Ive got:

```
/home/user/www
```

The only way I've been able to get this all working is by:

`chown -R www-data:www-data /home/user/www`

I'd like to be able to connect as 'user' using WinSCP and edit the contents of `/home/user/www` but I've tried all sorts of user and group permissions and cant get it working. I'm sure there are some basics of permissions that I'm not understanding. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `user` to the `www-data` group:

```
$ useradd -G www-data user
```

Set proper permissions on the target folder:

```
$ chown -R user.www-data /home/user/www
$ chmod -R g+w /home/user/www
```

The two above commands set the file/directory ownership properly and then grant the group owner write permissions.

Comment: I'd already somehow managed to add the user to www-data group! Thanks

Comment: isnt it giving 775 for a web root is a security risk? becos we are giving entire group the write access to the web root.